Get the BEEF ensemble energies (both mean and standard deviation) from the Quantuam Espresso output file (pw.pwo)
How do I get the Bayesian Error Estimate Functional with van der Waals correction (BEEF-vdw) ensemble energies (both the point and error estimate) from the Quantum Espresso output file? Thanks for the help!

Welcome! This is a good question. I think it will help if you make a small edit in spelling our the BEEF acronym.

I think the ensemble keywords available in pw.x is deprecated unfortunately, info from Paolo Giannozzi himself
